# Lottie - INTERACTIVE web based animation with raster IMAGES

Tags: javascript, css, json, lottie, bodymovin

I'm new to Lottie, have had some tutorial and tests completed, and got fascinated with the idea of mixing together After Effects animation with HTML5 animation. THANK YOU AB&B GENIES!

We're about to develop an online interactive project in which we'll cover our client's fashion collection.

The problem is, we'll have to use raster PNG images, rather than AE vector, because the client's got an exclusive waterpaint guideline for images.

Please have a look in this (closest) example of image ->[Fashion woman waterpaint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tuKTE.jpg)

We'll have different models (male and female) standing in idle position. Like, breathing, moving a little bit, like they're alive. We're planning to have their body parts and clothes in raster PNG images, animated with AE and exported with Lottie Bodymovin.

Then, we'd like to have [BUTTONS] which would help out the user to change these models clothes, like experimenting new fashion styles, colors, stamps, etc. A limited and pre-set range of PNG clothes will be used, to cover up the new collection.

How does Lottie work with changing such pre-set images, when clicking a button on runtime? Is it possible? The application will be hosted on an online server, and played on browser for an specific event, so no need to think about android or ios this time.

I'd like some references, please, I'm a bit lost around LottieAnimationView and setImageAssetDelegate, both which I can't see how to implement - if those are the proper solutions.

Thank you guys!

Comment: Hi People!
Anyone? Any Ideas?